# Multiple objects to clipboard

Tags: java, javafx, awt, clipboard

My problem is that I would like to copy some *text* **and** *an image* to the system's clipboard. I have tried with awt, and javafx but have not found the way to do it.

I've tried the awt solution for a single image. Not sure how to add multiple content.

```
MyTransferableImage image = new MyTransferableImage();
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(image, this);
```

and the javafx solution:

```
Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
content.putImage(myImage);
// edited
clipboard.setContent(content);
```

But neither was able to store multiple elements on clipboard.

Comment: from the api doc: _Clipboard operates on the concept of having a single conceptual item on the clipboard at any one time_ please read it to understand what you can/not expect .. If still stuck, come back with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem in the constraints of the api :)

Comment: @kleopatra thank you. maybe the examples are misleading, i am searching for some solution. I would like to put some text and an image on the clipboard at the same time and paste it in some windows environment. Sorry for the misleading, i am a bit rookie in stackoverflow. Feel free to edit the question. :)

Comment: repeating: you __can't__ because Clipboard only supports a single item (which may come in different formats, though)

Comment: @kleopatra what do you mean on single item? I can add multiple files for example, which is not a single item in my read. I can add different types of objects as a map to the clipboard. Extracting is another issue. For example i've added a list of images as files and i was able to paste them.

Comment: @kleopatra, explicitly adding elements to the ClipboardContent allows to store multiple items yet each of them should be of a unique format, for example, you can add a String, an HTML and an URL to the `ClipboardContent`, and then retrieve them according to their `DataFormat`, in this case, String, HTML and URL respectively, as documented in ClipboardContent : *Data container for Clipboard data. It can hold multiple data in several data formats.* However, system's copy/cut seems to overwrite every DataFormat, which means, it is not possible to store multiple items in that case.

Comment: @adxl don't quite understand which part of _single_ item (in different formats) is so hard to understand

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting the created content to the `ClipBoard` :

```
final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();

// Add your elements
content.putString("Text");
content.putImage(new Image("https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/img/cb88-java-logo-001.jpg"));

// Set the Clipboard's content
clipboard.setContent(content);
```

ref: [Clipboard : Oracle Help Center](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/ClipboardContent.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i am only able to paste the image content on windows.